# Subclipse (SVN) Compare showing similar files

Tags: eclipse, svn, merge, compare, subclipse

It seems whenever I compare via the SVN Repository explorer (most recently after a merge) subclipse will show a few files in the compare window that have no differences whatsoever. Double clicking the file brings up the Java Source Compare window, but Subclipse highlights no sections and shows no differences. A manual inspection of the file shows they are identical. What causes this? Are there any ways to disable it, it can be quite confusing?

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I forgot to mention, a compare with tortoise does not display the files, although I'd much rather use the subclipse compare.

Comment: What version of SVN are you using?  Is the behavior isolated to when you are performing a merge?  Do the files in question have the svn:mergeinfo property set?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it could be whitespace-related. Maybe tortoise defaults to ignoring ws changes.

Comment: When You have problem with whitespaces, Eclipse highlights at least tabs. But it's not the case - here application doesn't highlight nothing. If You have such problem, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536237/eclipse-cvs-file-compare.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be Eclipse bug, which waits for solution...

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=318826

Answer (score 0):

There may not be structural change, but only space related or formatting. Try clicking on "next difference".

Comment: it is not related to spaces, it is related to revision change

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that after merging the revision of the file is changed. So, although the content of files is the same, the compare view shows the change. It is very very bad... :(