# Eclipse CVS file compare

Tags: eclipse, cvs

When I compare two identical files one from my eclipse workspace and one from repository eclipse compare editor shows differences all over the file. It even shows the tab characters in the differences. Is there any setting that will tell editor to ignore the tab characters?

Answer (score 5):

You can interactivly influence the whitespace comparison in the compare view from the context menu of the view in Eclipse Helios.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

We actually encountered this yesterday on my development team.

From the `Window | Preferences | General | Compare/Patch` dialog, click the **Ignore white space** option and that should clear things up for you.